# Elasticsearch FunctionScore query using Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I need to implement the below function_score query using Java APIs. I couldn't find any official documentation for function_score query in the Java API section of elasticsearch

```
"function_score": {
    "functions": [
        {
            "boost_factor": "3",
            "filter": {
                 "terms" : {"course_cd" : ["writ100", "writ112", "writ113"] }   
            }
        }
    ],
    "query": {
          "match" : {
               "party_id" : "12"
          }
     }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: which version of elasticsearch are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Jörg

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.functionscore.FunctionScoreQueryBuilder;
import java.util.Arrays;
import static org.elasticsearch.client.Requests.searchRequest;
import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.FilterBuilders.termsFilter;
import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.matchQuery;
import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.functionscore.ScoreFunctionBuilders.factorFunction;
import static org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.searchSource;

public class FunctionScoreTest {

    public void testFunctionScore() {
        SearchRequest searchRequest = searchRequest()
                .source(searchSource().query(new FunctionScoreQueryBuilder(matchQuery("party_id", "12"))
                        .add(termsFilter("course_cd", Arrays.asList("writ100", "writ112", "writ113")), factorFunction(3.0f))));
    }
}
```